# How to calculate total sales for music

Tags: ruby, csv

I am trying retrieve information from a CSV file:

```
require 'csv'

total_sales = 0

CSV.foreach('sales-data.csv', headers: true, converters: :all) do |row|
  # TODO: check if category is "Music" (row[2])
  # TODO: if it is music, add total_sales + the row's sales (row[6])
  if row[2] = 'music'
    total_sales = total_sales + row[6]
end

puts total_sales.round(2)
```

When I run this code, I receive this error:

```
our-sales-report.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, 
expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need to be able to duplicate the problem which requires the minimum input data that demonstrates it, along with the required output.

Answer (score 1):

Generally every `if` should have a corresponding `end`, and yours doesn't. Also you'll want to be very, very careful about confusing the `=` assignment operator and the `==` comparison one. The correct code is:

```
if row[2] == 'music'
  # ...
end
```

The only exceptions are trailing `if` clauses:

```
total_sales += row[6] if row[2] == 'music'
```

I'd advise beginners to steer away from those at first as they can lead to mind-bendingly confusing code if abused. Note that `x += y` is shorthand for `x = x + y` and often communicates what's happening much more clearly.

One other thing to consider is writing code this way:

```
case row[2]
when 'music'
  total_sales += row[6]
end
```

That way it's impossible to do an accidental assignment.

Another thing to consider is to break out your `row` into actual column names, like this:

```
CSV.foreach(...) do |a, b, type, c, d, sales|
```

Where `a` and `b` are changed to represent whatever value is present in that column. That is a lot more readable than `row[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby isn't python : unindenting code isn't enough to close a block or a statement :

```
if row[2] == 'music'
  total_sales = total_sales + row[6]
end # <------------ this was missing!!!
```